# How to write a batch script to run multiple adb shell commands

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd, adb

I want to write a batch script that will first start adb shell via `adb shell`  and then run some commands like  `input swipe 77 1161 77 1161 500` and then `input tap 157 1066` and so on. But I'm unable to do so. I've tried multiple ways but none seems to work. I've tried writing script like:

```
 adb shell "input swipe 86 1186 86 1186 500;input tap 157 1066"
```

and writing commands on seperate lines like,

```
adb shell "input swipe 86 1186 86 1186 500;
input tap 157 1066"
```

and also tried putting adb shell in one file and putting other commands in seperate file but nothing works. I always end up getting this jarring screen in cmd even if I put an exit in the end of the commands.[image]

I want to know whether i'm doing the right thing the wrong way or something else.. Please explain what's the best way to do it and please explain thoroughly. Any help will be appericiated. Thanks.

Comment: The first option should just work. What happens if you do something like `adb shell "echo 1; echo 2"` instead?

Comment: @user202729 I haven't tried to echo any other text other than adb shell commands, Why could this be happening?

Comment: What's the name of your script file?

Comment: @user202729 adb.bat

Comment: Obviously that's the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the problem.why is that the problem.. and whats the solution

Comment: I think.. So there's adb.exe in my PC.. and I have named the bat file "adb.bat" is the problem? Naming it anything else will do the work properly?